# Yourkit API heap dump analysis

Tags: java, api, profiler, yourkit

Is it possible to use yourkit API (https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/api/index.html) to inspect the objects in the heap?
Inspecting means, for example, getting the values of the fields of objects in the heap.

The class MemorySnapshot seems rather limited.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on what you mean by *inspect*.  The API does provide some ways to count and get the size of sets of objects.  The set [specification](https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/language.jsp) is pretty extensive.  The Yourkit business model is to allow free use of the APIs but charge for the UI.  So it is against their interests to allow too much to be done in the API.